# My Oracle Forms Builder is not able to Run or Execute any Form

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I am getting error saying "The HTTP listner is not running on intel at prot 8889 .Please start the listener or check your runtime preferences."

Answer (score 1):

To run the form you must first start the `OC4J` server. You do so by going into **start -> programs** into the `Oracle Forms Developer` folder then you will see an icon for Start OC4J. You must always start this prior to tuning your forms systems.

Answer (score 0):

I am using oracle 10gr2 in windows 8 64-bit .. in my start menu i have 'Start OC4J Instance' and 'Shutdown OC4J Instance' . Been there and done that . still my forms are not running . Is it related to internet explorer or any preferences i read on google that oracle 9i onwards forms executes on IE window

Comment: The problem may be that Forms 10 is supported on Windows 8 or not even at Windows 7. Please do also notice that Forms 10 was de supported by Oracle some time ago. If possible please move to Forms 11.